# Error: field name cannot be declared static

Tags: java, multithreading, static, inner-classes

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final class Constants {
            public static String name = "globe";
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Constants.name);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Compilation Error: `The field name cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression`

Solution to this?

Comment: Did you try making `Constants` a static type?

Comment: Not declare the String in Constants or make final class Constants also static (and probably not declare it inside the main method).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does not let you define non-final static fields inside function-local inner classes. Only top-level classes and static nested classes are allowed to have non-final static fields.

If you want a `static` field in your `Constants` class, put it at the `Application` class level, like this:

```
public class Application {
    static final class Constants {
        public static String name = "globe";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Constants.name);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect - if the field is made `final` within the original code it will compile, because it's initialized with a constant value.

Comment: Now the variable `name` should be declare `final`

Comment: @micro.pravi: If you make it `final`, you can make `Constants` a local class again..

Answer (score 6):

From the [JLS section 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

So you're fine if you just make the variable `final`:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final class Constants {
            public static final String name = "globe";
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Constants.name);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Of course this won't work if you need to initialize it with a non-constant value.

Having said all of this, it's an unusual design, IMO. It's very rare to see a named local class at all, in my experience. Do you *need* this to be a local class? What are you trying to achieve?