# Field can't be static?

Tags: java, static, nested-class

There is error with this code

```
public class DoIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final class Apple {
            public static String place = "doIt";
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Constants.place);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Error- `The field name cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression`

Comment: What is Constants.place? How you make use of the Apple class in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: field name cannot be declared static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526099/error-field-name-cannot-be-declared-static)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the field is non-final: only final fields are allowed to be static in the context of non-static inner classes:

```
final class Apple {
    // This should compile
    public static final String place = "doIt";
}
```

Comment: But Why is it?As I can change the field in this method.

Comment: @JohnnyChen You cannot get to that class from another method, because it is method-scoped. There's no way to say `Apple.place = "something-else";` outside of `main`, because `Apple` is not visible from there. If you need to make it changeable inside `main`, then use a different mechanism of making it work.

Answer (score 1):

[JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

```
final class Apple {
    public static final String place = "doIt"; // This is good
}
```

Inner classes are instance classes. The point of using a *static* member is to call it directly without having to instantiate. So it wouldn't make much sense to allow static members inside an inner class. However, you can declare them as static-

```
static final class Apple {
    public static String place = "doIt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final class Apple { {  
     // you can't define non final field inside the final class
     // you have to use final with static

 }
```

you can use

```
   public  final static String place = "doIt";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#local-classes-are-non-static),

> A local class can have static members provided that they are constant variables.

So you would have to declare it final:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final class Apple {
        public static final String place = "doIt";
    }
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before i reason out the error terminology is as follows

**Terminology:** Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes(**more specifically local inner class**).

Now in your case you have  local inner class. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `Because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.`

Objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance of the outer class and static members are loaded when classes are loaded whereas in your case you cannot access `Apple` class at the time of class loading to load  `place` variable.

Also A local class can have static members provided that they are constant variables.

so you can do `public static final String place = "doIt";`